Is it possible to change zfs raid-z1 to raid-z2 or raid-z3 on for instance TrueNas scale
I have a running truenas-scale zfs on raid-z1. For safety I though of increasing parity when adding a new disk.
Asking the same question as someone asked 10 years ago,
is it possible with the current state of ZFS in 2024 or is it still not supported to change from one raidz type to another when adding disks?
